# A2 regional quota limit on Google Compute Engine doesn't increase

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, quota

I am trying to set up an  a2-highgpu-1g instance in us-central1-a on Google Compute Engine.

I got the following error when setting the instance up:  - Quota 'A2_CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 0.0 in region us-central1.

Therefore i requested an A2 CPU quota increase in the region us-central1.
It got automatically approved, but in the approvement e-mail it says:  CPUS_ALL_REGIONS | GLOBAL |        12, which is different from what i requested.

Also the A2 CPU limit in the us-central1 region is still at 0. How can i get this limit increased?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like Google increased your CPU quota to 12 but not the A2 CPU quota. That might be a human error or a denial. Only Google Cloud can help you change quotas. If your account is new or the credit card has limited credit available, quota increases are sometimes denied. A quota increase is similar to asking for a credit line increase. Try contacting Google Cloud Billing support.

Comment: You can simply reply to the quota email you received and ask some clarification or contact the [sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply for an increase for the A100 GPU limit quota. If it is approved, it automatically increases the limit for the A2 CPUs as well.